# Combine javafx and spring, parameter isn't passed?

Tags: java, spring, javafx-2

I trying using spring as a configuration to set the layout for javaFx. Which lead me to the codes belows...

Spring XML file:

```
<bean id="test2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <!-- <ref bean="test"/> -->

        <bean class="bin.client.xTest01_CallJavaFx">
            <property name="TextVar ">                                              
                <value>Ali 2 baba</value>               
            </property>             
        </bean>

    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>genUI</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The javaFx file :

```
public class xTest01_CallJavaFx extends Application{    

public String TextVar = new String();

public String getTextVar () {
    return TextVar ;
}
public void setTextVar (String arg) {
    this.TextVar = arg;
}

public void start(Stage stage){     

    System.out.println( textVar ); // Variable can't be detected

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,200,100);
    //root.getChildren().add(new Text(50,50,"Hello World"));
    root.getChildren().add(new Text(50,50, textVar ) );  // UI generated with 
                                 // empty text field
    //root.getChildren().add(new Text(50,50,textVar));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public void genUI(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Set here : " + textVar ); // able to display value from 
                                    // spring
    launch(args);   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  // Run the program !
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext( "C:/welcome.xml" );
    Class trvProcess;       
    trvProcess = (Class)context.getBean("test2");
}
```

Anyone know why the variable injection from spring manage to get into the bean but accessable after extends with javafx ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your set method is wrong:

```
public void setTextVar (String arg) {
    this.TextVar = TextVar ;
}
```

should be

```
public void setTextVar (String arg) {
    this.TextVar = arg ;
}
```

The bigger issue is that the launch(...) method creates a new instance of your class and calls its start(...) method. So, of course, that's not the instance on which the field is set by Spring. If you want to use Spring and JavaFX together, I recommend reading [this blog](http://www.zenjava.com/series/building-jee-applications-in-javafx-2-0/).

Comment: Ah, yes... I see what's happening but I'm not sure how you fix this.

Comment: Now i suspecting extends on default will initialize the javaFx objects... which at point in time variable not yet set.... and draw the UI stage out.... When spring call for the javafx it is calling the ready made object without reapplying the injected variable...hmm....